# Vue v-for loop with day subheaders

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm re-building an existing schedule page as a Vue.JS app, and I'm trying to end up with something like the following DOM. (I'm brand new to Vue, and have seen a lot of examples of v-for loops, but I'm wondering how to even approach my particular loop requirements.)

```
<ul class="days">
  <li class="day">
    Feb 14
    <ul class="events">
      <li class="event">Event 1</li>
      <li class="event">Event 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="day">
    Feb 15
    <ul class="events">
      <li class="event">Event 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My data is currently structured as follows:

```
events: [
  {
    "Name": "Event 1",
    "StartDateTime": "February 14, 2019 08:00:00"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Event 2",
    "StartDateTime": "February 14, 2019 09:00:00"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Event 3",
    "StartDateTime": "February 15, 2019 08:00:00"
  }
]
```

Should I use plain ol' JS to loop through the data, convert each StartDateTime to a day, filter the result so there aren't any duplicates, store that data as a separate days object in Vue's data, and then do some kind of nested v-for first on the days and second on the events within that day? And how would I tell the nested events v-for to match the day? Or is there a much better Vue way to approach this entire thing? Thank you!

Comment: I could also restructure my response so that the JSON data was a bunch of days each containing their own nested events, but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to work with it as-is.

Comment: It would definitely make more sense if you had an array of days that had a child array of events for that day.. You could create a computed property to map the events to dates then run a v-for over that computed property. But, then again that would be your call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to return a data structure that facilitates iterating your event data grouped by date. The following code uses [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a lookup `Object`, with the key being the date parsed from each event's `StartDateTime`, and the value being an array of events within the corresponding date:

```
computed: {
  eventDates() {
    return this.events.reduce((p,c) => {
      const date = new Date(c.StartDateTime).toDateString();
      p[date] = p[date] || [];
      p[date].push(c);
      return p;
    }, {});
  }
},
```

Then in your template, use [`v-for` with that `Object`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object):

```
<ul class="days">
  <li class="day" v-for="(events, date) in eventDates">
    {{date}}
    <ul class="events">
      <li class="event" v-for="event in events">{{event.Name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    events: [
      {
        "Name": "Event 1",
        "StartDateTime": "February 14, 2019 08:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Event 2",
        "StartDateTime": "February 14, 2019 09:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Event 3",
        "StartDateTime": "February 15, 2019 08:00:00"
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    eventDates() {
      return this.events.reduce((p,c) => {
        const date = new Date(c.StartDateTime).toDateString();
        p[date] = p[date] || [];
        p[date].push(c);
        return p;
      }, {});
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.5/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul class="days">
    <li class="day" v-for="(events, date) in eventDates">
      {{date}}
      <ul class="events">
        <li class="event" v-for="event in events">{{event.Name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is exactly what I need! Really helps to see the syntax for grouping by date in the first v-for, and the power of computed values. You definitely bridged a gap for me between the intro tutorials and the more advanced stuff. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Michael No problem :)

Comment: Thanks @tony19, helped my brain get over the hurdle.